# Mapping YOLO results onto 2D plan

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, 2d, yolo, bounding-box

I'm using YOLO to detect people in a video stream from camera and would like to "map" founded bonding boxes onto 2D plan of the room.

Could you please give me a hint which algorithms might be used for it?

The idea is shown on the picture from the github repository, but I need not to measure distance but "project" an object position on 2D map of the room

https://github.com/sassoftware/iot-tracking-social-distancing-computer-vision

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try to have a look at the repo https://github.com/sassoftware/iot-tracking-social-distancing-computer-vision

Comment: Another repo to have a look at
https://github.com/vita-epfl/monoloco

Answer (score 2):

Using 3D cameras or just 2 regular ones might help a lot as well